# The third internalFormat of qglTexImage2D in Quake2

Tags: c, opengl, quake2

From Quake2 source, the function GL_BeginBuildingLightmaps at gl_rsufr.c, i saw these codes:

```
if ( toupper( gl_monolightmap->string[0] ) == 'A' )
{
    gl_lms.internal_format = gl_tex_alpha_format;
}
/*
** try to do hacked colored lighting with a blended texture
*/
else if ( toupper( gl_monolightmap->string[0] ) == 'C' )
{
    gl_lms.internal_format = gl_tex_alpha_format;
}
else if ( toupper( gl_monolightmap->string[0] ) == 'I' )
{
    gl_lms.internal_format = GL_INTENSITY8;
}
else if ( toupper( gl_monolightmap->string[0] ) == 'L' ) 
{
    gl_lms.internal_format = GL_LUMINANCE8;
}
else
{
    gl_lms.internal_format = gl_tex_solid_format;
}
GL_Bind( gl_state.lightmap_textures + 0 );
qglTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
qglTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
qglTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
               0, 
               gl_lms.internal_format,
               BLOCK_WIDTH, BLOCK_HEIGHT, 
               0, 
               GL_LIGHTMAP_FORMAT, 
               GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
               dummy );
```

### `qglTexImage2D` is same as glTexImage2D.

The problem is from debugging i saw the input value of third parameter(internalFormat) of `qglTexImage2D` is `gl_tex_solid_format`, which is 3. Is 3 a valid value for parameter internalFormat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`3` is a perfectly legitimate value for `internalFormat`.

From the [the `glTexImage2D()` documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml):

> `internalFormat`: Specifies the number of color components in the texture. **Must be 1, 2, 3, or 4**, or one of the following symbolic constants: ...

Comment: I was confused for reading the wrong opengl version document.I should read the opengl version 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the value of the variable gl_tex_solid_format from? Are you sure you have assigned GL_RGBA to the variable gl_tex_solid_format? Maybe you assigned 3 to the variable gl_tex_solid_format.